# how to configure active directory authentication for oracle database and oracle acces manager

Tags: oracle, active-directory

i have got a use case where i need to authenticate into oracle database and oracle access manager using the user details in active directory.. can any one help with this

Thanks,
Rakesh KR

Answer (score 0):

Topic is to broad to answer in SO:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b32010/active_dir.htm